# Intermediate fields of splitting field

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to find the intermediate fields of the extension $\mathbb Q\big /\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, where $\alpha = \sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}$. To do so I've tried to use the Galois correspondence. I've already found that $\rm{Gal}\left(\mathbb Q\big /\mathbb Q(\alpha)\right)$ has order $4$ and that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z$, which has three subgroups of order 2. Therefore, there must be three normal intermediate fields in the extension.

$E:=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)=x^4-14x^2+36$, which has $4$ roots numbered as:

$$\left\{\alpha_1 = \alpha, \alpha_2 = -\sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}, \alpha_3 = \sqrt{7-\sqrt{13}}, \alpha_4 = -\sqrt{7-\sqrt{13}}\right\}.$$

Then, the automorphisms in $\rm{Gal}\left(\mathbb Q\big /\mathbb Q(\alpha)\right)$ are

$$\sigma_1(\alpha) = \alpha_1$$
$$\sigma_2(\alpha) = \alpha_2$$
$$\sigma_3(\alpha) = \alpha_3$$
$$\sigma_4(\alpha) = \alpha_4$$

**EDIT: corrected subgroups**

If we see them as elements of $S_4$, they are $id, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)$, respectively. Thus, the subgroups are $H_1:=\langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle, H_2:=\langle(1,3)(2,4)\rangle$ and $H_3:=\langle(1,4)(2,3)\rangle$ (all isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z$).

Then, to find the intermediate fields I'm looking for $E^{H_i}=\{x\in E\mid \sigma(x), \forall\sigma\in H_i\}$

However, when I try with $H_2$, for example, it gets very nasty. In this case we'd have to impose that $\sigma_2(\gamma)=\gamma$ for all $\gamma\in E$. On the one hand, since $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ is a $\mathbb Q-$basis for $E$,

$$\gamma = a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+a_3\alpha^3,\qquad a_i\in\mathbb Q$$

On the other hand, we have

$$\sigma_2(\gamma) = a_0+a_1\sigma_2(\alpha)+a_2\sigma_2(\alpha^2)+a_3\sigma_3(\alpha^3)$$

$$=a_0-a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2-a_3\alpha^3$$

And then, coefficients of both expressions should be equal.

**EDIT: added manipulations of these expressions**

From these expressions we get that $\alpha_1=\alpha_3=0$ and $\alpha_0,\alpha_2$ are free (so it has 2 degrees of freedom as expected).

$$\Rightarrow E^{H_2}=\{a+b(7+\sqrt{13})\mid a, b\in \mathbb Q\}=\mathbb Q(7+\sqrt{13})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13}).$$

So, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13})$ is the intermediate field that corresponds to the group $H_2$.

But I don't know how to do it with the other subgroups..

With $\sigma_3(\alpha) = \alpha_3 = \frac{6}{\alpha}$,

$$\sigma_3(\gamma) = a_0+a_1\frac{6}{\alpha}+a_2\left(\frac{6}{\alpha}\right)^2+a_3\left(\frac{6}{\alpha}\right)^3$$

Comment: Something is wrong here. The permutations: $id, (12), (13), (14)$ do not form a group. For example $(12)(13)=(132)$. If the group has only four elements (I think that is correct), then the non-identity elements cannot have fixed points among the four roots.

Comment: You're right. However, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\big / \mathbb Q$ is simple and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, so the automorphisms are defined by the mappings of $\alpha$ to the roots of the polynomial $f=\rm{Irr}\left(\alpha,\mathbb Q\right)$. I don't see where is my mistake

Comment: That is true, but if $\sigma_2$ is defined as the automorphism that maps $\alpha\mapsto\alpha_2$, then (exactly because the automorphism is already fully determined) you cannot conclude that $\sigma_2(\alpha_3)=\alpha_3$. It turns out that instead we are forced to have $\sigma_2(\alpha_3)=\alpha_4$. This shouldn't be a surprise, because
$$\alpha_1\alpha_3=\sqrt{(7+\sqrt{13})(7-\sqrt{13})}=\sqrt{7^2-13}=6.$$ So we must have $\sigma(\alpha_3)=6/\sigma(\alpha_1)$ for all the automorphisms $\sigma$. If $\sigma$ moves $\alpha_1$, it must also move $\alpha_3$ and vice versa.

Comment: Okay, now I see it, but isn't there any easier way to determine where $\sigma_2$ sends the other roots? Is there any general method?

Comment: Well, if you know that the other roots are in the field generated by one of the roots, here $\alpha$, doesn't that imply that you already know how to write the other roots in terms of $\alpha$? The automorphisms must respect such relations. How did you conclude that $\alpha_3\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ here?

Comment: +1 You're right. At first, that relation between $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ looked very non-trivial to me. But, actually, is the way that I checked that $\alpha_3\in\mathbb Q(\alpha)$... Thanks

Comment: Good. +1 to the question, the effort and the learning process :-)

Comment: @Jyrki The sqrt denests [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14#comment2471468_1214527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general method to deal with these sorts of extensions. Suppose we have $F$ a field of characteristic not equal to $2$ and suppose we adjoin $\alpha = \sqrt{a + b\sqrt{c}}$ Suppose that $b\neq0$, $a^2 - b^2c = h^2$ for some $h\in F$. Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a + b\sqrt{c}}$ (put some nice conditions on $a,b,c$ so that $F(\alpha)$ is an extension of degree $4$).

Let us call $\alpha_1 = \alpha$ , $\alpha_2 = \sqrt{a - b\sqrt{c}}$, $-\alpha_1= \alpha_3$ and $-\alpha_2 = \alpha_4$. We choose the following presentation for $V_4$ (the Klein 4- group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$): $$V_4 = \{e, (12)(34), (13)(24),(14)(23)\}.$$ Note that $(14)(23) = \big((13)(24)\big)\big((12)(34)\big)$. Then we can see that each cycle in $V_4$ acts on the roots according to the numbering convention: For example the cycle $(12)(34)$ sends  $\alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_2$, $\alpha_3\mapsto \alpha_4$. Now for the sake of simplicity let us call

$$\theta = (12)(34), \hspace{5mm} \gamma = (13)(24), \hspace{5mm} \gamma\theta = (14)(23).$$

Then it is easy to see that $\theta(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \gamma\theta(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) = \alpha_1 - \alpha_2$. Now because $\gamma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_3$, squaring both sides we see that $\gamma(\sqrt{c} ) = \sqrt{c}$. It follows from these observations that

$$F(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \subset E^{\langle \theta \rangle}, \hspace{5mm} F(\sqrt{c}) \subset E^{\langle \gamma \rangle}, \hspace{5mm} F(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) \subset E^{\langle \gamma\theta\rangle }.$$

By computing minimal polynomials/degrees we get that these subset inclusions are actually equalities and so you are done.

**Edit:** As Jyrki points out, the only presentation for $V_4$ that we can choose is the one given in my answer as that presentation is the only one which gives a transitive subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: +1: But it is not always clear that you can **choose** the permutation presentation of the Galois group just from knowing its isomorphism type. In this case it **is** ok, because that is the only **transitive** copy of $V_4$ inside $S_4$. Transitivity coming from irreducibility of the polynomial we started with. In general you have to calculate the action of the automorphisms on the roots from their definitions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree. That's why when I studied Galois theory I was completely stunned to find that we can have two - copies of $V_4$ inside of $S_4$, one normal and one not!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We had such a problem as an assignment to do; when I was doing this assignment I was trying so hard to understand as to ***why*** the copy of $V_4 = \{e,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$ just wouldn't work and your comment above says exactly why.

Comment: The last part is not very clear to me. I don't see how you determine so easily that those fields are in fact the intermediate fields. Is there a way to prove it using the fixed elements and a basis as I proposed in my question?

Comment: @Kits89 This should be clear from the definition of $\theta$ and $\gamma$. For example I have already chosen a numbering of the roots. If you look at the automorphism $\theta = (12)(34)$ what do you think it most obviously fixes? Well it sends $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$ so if you take their ***sum*** this will be fixed by $\theta$ yes?

Comment: Yes, that is true. My doubt also was in *why* choosing $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ and not, for example, $\alpha_3+\alpha_4$ or $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4$. But now I see that $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) = \mathbb Q(\alpha_3+\alpha_4)$, because we found those relations between the roots. So, okay, it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{2}}, \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)$. In fact, as in the post of @BenjaLim, if $a^2 - b^2 c$ is a square (in $\mathbf{Q}$, in this case), you can solve
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} = \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}
\end{equation}
for $u, v \in \mathbf{Q}$, as they are the solutions of $x^2 - a x + \dfrac{b² c}{4} = 0$. Rewriting the extension this way makes the computations of the Galois group and of the intermediate fields slightly easier.

Thus, we are regarding the extension  $\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{2}}, \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right) / \mathbf{Q}$ as the splitting field of the *reducible* polynomial
\begin{equation}
\left(x^2 - \dfrac{13}{2}\right) \cdot \left(x^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}\right),
\end{equation}
whose roots are
\begin{equation}
\beta_{1} = \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}}, \quad
\beta_{2} = - \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}}, \quad
\beta_{3} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}, \quad
\beta_{4} = - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation}
If you regard the Galois group as a permutation group acting on the indices of the $\beta_i$, it takes the form $\{1,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$. Not a transitive group, but the roots are those of a reducible polynomial here.

The intermediate subfields of course are
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{2}}\right), \quad
\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right), \quad
\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{2}} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)
=
\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt{13}\right)
.
\end{equation}

**EDIT** In a previous version I had made an incorrect claim. Thanks to @Kits89 for letting me know in his comment below.

Comment: Your basis is not $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent, $\beta_1 = -\beta_2$

Comment: So, by your answer I see that the extension is actually: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: And could you explain the rationale of that factorization, please? Why the roots of the polynomial $x^2-ax+\frac{b^2c}{4}$ give it?

Comment: @Kits89 Thanks for your first comment. Let me fix this, and I will come back to the third one.

Comment: As to your third comment, square both sides of $\sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} = \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}$ to get $a+b \sqrt{c} = u+v + 2 \sqrt{u v}$. Comparing, you obtain $u+v=a$ and $uv = b^2 c /4$, so that $u,v$ are the roots of that quadratic equation.

The rationale of the factorization, though, is best seen by starting from $\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$ (where $u, v, uv$ are not squares in $\mathbf{Q}$), finding the polynomial over $\mathbf{Q}$ of degree 4 of which this is the root, noticing that it is a biquadratic, and now solving with the usual substitution $y = x^2$ to get the form $\sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}}$.

Comment: What happens if $b=1$ and $a=c$?