# Minimal polynomial over the field $\Bbb Q$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Compute the minimal polynomials over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of the given numbers

1. $\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{2}}$
2. $\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{3}}$
3. $5^\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Some of the observations made here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288036/intermediate-fields-of-splitting-field/288059#288059 might be useful.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer:**

Let $\alpha =\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{2}}$. It holds that 
$$\begin{align}
\alpha =\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{2}} &\Longrightarrow \alpha ^2 = 2 +i\sqrt{2}\\
&\Longrightarrow \alpha^2-2=i\sqrt{2}\\
&\Longrightarrow \alpha ^4 -4\alpha ^2 + 4=-2\\ 
&\Longrightarrow \alpha ^4 -4\alpha ^2 +6=0
\end{align}$$

It follows that $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $m_\alpha(t)$ whee $\displaystyle m_\alpha(t):=t^4-4t^2+6\in \mathbb{Q} \textbf{[}t\textbf{]}$.

Could it be that $m_\alpha$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? Ask [Eisenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

The others are similar.

Comment: So for the third one, I get x^4-5=0, and using Eisenstein's criterion for p=5 we can show that it is irreducible over Q, also it is primitive so it is minimal? right?

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar $x^4 - 5$ is the minimal polynomial of $\displaystyle 5^{\frac{1}{4}}$ because it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ because of Eisentein, because it is a monic polynomial and because $\displaystyle (5^{\frac{1}{4}})^4-5=0$. I don't see how primitive polynomials related to this.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show some polynomial monic and irreducible to show it is minimal?

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar Yes, that's what I explained.

Comment: Thank you ! Greatly appreciated

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar No problem.