# how to simplify $ 2 \sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}} \right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

How to simplify

$$
2 \sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}} \right)
$$

so that it has no nested radicals?
This question is same as that already posted but with a different point of view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}}=2\sqrt{2}\left( \sqrt{\frac{9+2}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{9-2}{2}}\right)=2\sqrt{11}-2\sqrt{7}
$$

By the formula:
$$
\sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{a+ \sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{a- \sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}
$$
that can easily verified and works well when $a^2-b$ is a perfect square.

You can see my answer to [Denesting a square root: $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{14}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14/1454914#1454914)

Comment: can you prove the formula?

Comment: simply square the two sides and simplify.

Answer (score 4):

$$2^{3/2} \bigl(9-77^{1/2}\bigr)^{1/2}= 2\bigl(18-2\cdot77^{1/2}\bigr)^{1/2}=2\Bigl(\bigl(11^{1/2}-7^{1/2}\bigr)^2\Bigr)^{1/2}=2(11^{1/2}-7^{1/2}).$$

Answer (score 4):

$$2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}} = 2\sqrt{18-2\sqrt{7\cdot 11}} = 2\sqrt{(\sqrt{11}-\sqrt{7})^2} = 2\sqrt{11}-2\sqrt{7}.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?