# What is the error in this square root denesting?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

Following Bill/Number's [denesting rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1863783/167548), I attempted to denest the follow nested radical:

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$$

The norm evaluates to $4-3=1$, and subtracting it out gives $1+\sqrt3$. 
The trace evaluates to $\sqrt4=2$, so dividing it out yields $\dfrac{1+\sqrt3}2$; however, this is not equal to the original expression. What is the error I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the trace of $1+\sqrt3$ not $2+\sqrt3$. You get
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Oops, thanks for the clarification