# Partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+\sqrt{4k^2-1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+\sqrt{4k^2-1}}}$ is divergent. I am interested in its partial sums to do some computations based on them.

I tried to multiply $\sqrt{2k+\sqrt{4k^2-1}}$ by $\sqrt{2k-\sqrt{4k^2-1}}$ and to divide by the same term, but I have got no telescoping sum for evaluation. Maybe I should use others technics.

Now my question is what is the closed form of the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+\sqrt{4k^2-1}}}\ ?$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863684/fully-simplify-sqrt-14-8-sqrt-3/1863783#1863783)

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(a+\sqrt{a^2-b}\right)}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2-b}\right)}$$

where: $a = 2 k$ and $b=4 k^2-1$, along with evaluating a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general), we find that

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 k+\sqrt{4 k^2-1}}}}&=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{-1+2 k}+\sqrt{1+2 k}}\\\\
&=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{2}
   \left(\sqrt{2 k+1}-\sqrt{2 k-1}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{-1+2 k}+\sqrt{1+2 k}\right) \left(\sqrt{2 k+1}-\sqrt{2 k-1}\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n
   \left(\sqrt{2 k+1}-\sqrt{2 k-1}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\\\\
&=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+2 n}}{\sqrt{2}}\\\\
&=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{1+2 n}}{\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the slick answer

Comment: @zeraouliarafik . You're welcome `:)`

Comment: (+1) Nicely done.  But CAS is unnecessary.  Simply multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt(2k+1)-\sqrt(2k-1)$ to yield a telescoping series.

Comment: @MarkViola. Thanks for HINT.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.