# Is there formula to easily factorize $7+4 \sqrt{3}$ to $(2+ \sqrt{3} )^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, factoring

Is there some formula to easily guess that:

$7+4\sqrt{3}$ can be factorize to: $(2+ \sqrt{3}) ^2$?

Only looking at $7+4\sqrt{3}$, it's difficult to guess that you can factorize like that.

EDIT: Duplicate of [Strategies to denest nested radicals $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals-sqrtab-sqrtc) , thanks @Martin_R

Comment: $(a+b\sqrt{3})^2 = a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt{3}$ then compare coefficients

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/196155/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917494/42969.

Comment: You can get a clue from the term $4\sqrt 3$ which is nothing but $2\cdot 2\cdot\sqrt 3$, so we can try to write it in the form $(a\pm b)^2$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: $7^2 - 3 \cdot 4^2 = 1,$   so possible factors will be $a+b \sqrt 3$   with $a^2 - 3 b^2 = 1$ as well.  The first few pirs with $a,b$ non-negative integers are $(1,0); (2,1) ; (7,4) ; (26,15); (97,56) . $

Comment: also $  ( 362 + 209 \sqrt 3) (26-15 \sqrt 3)  = 7 + 4 \sqrt 3 $