# Find the square root of $14+6\sqrt5 $

Tags: rational-numbers, nested-radicals

Find the square root of $14+6\sqrt5$

I don't just want the answer, can you please tell me the method how you get the answer

Comment: `I don't just want the answer` See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828493/how-do-you-simplify-this-square-root-of-sum-sqrt74-sqrt3) for example.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/196155/11619) or even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical).

Comment: You can check [Denesting radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at Wikipedia, You can find here several posts on similar problems on this site:
[Strategies to denest nested radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)), 
[Denesting a square root: $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{14}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527)
(and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1214527)).

Comment: You can probably find a few more posts about similar problems in the [nested-radicals tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-radicals). And you can use Approach0 [to search for some other similar problems](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B14%2B6%5Csqrt5%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(a+b \sqrt{5})^2 = 14 + 6 \sqrt{5}$$

Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Kindly fetch me complete solution, I'm bit confused

Comment: On this site, you have to show us your effort first.  Try to expand the quadratic term first and compare the coefficients. I can further tell you that $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: My expansion says $a$ =349.  And $b$=108.   I'm confused

Comment: How did you obtain $a=349$? what do you get upon expanding $(a+b \sqrt{5})^2$?

Answer (score 2):

As you expect the solution to be nice (as in you don't just write $\sqrt{14+6\sqrt{5}}$), one can use "creative writing" to receive a square via the binomial formula:

$$14+6\sqrt{5}=9+5+6\sqrt{5}=9+6\sqrt{5}+5=9+2\cdot 3\cdot\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}^2$$

I'm sure you can take it from here!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$6\sqrt5=2\cdot3\cdot\sqrt5$$

Compare with $$2ab$$ in $$a^2+b^2+2ab$$