# Please give me the method of writing $\sqrt{33 + 12 \sqrt 6}$ in the form $a + b \sqrt c$

Tags: radicals

I have the answer but I need the method. 
My professor wants it in : a + b √c.
He said a hint would be to use algebra.

Comment: "use algebra"...what a hint x)

Comment: What do you mean by "under $a+b\sqrt{c}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{33+12\sqrt6}=x+y\sqrt6$ (it must be $6$ altought $6a^2$ also but it is unuseful). It implies $2xy=12$ and $x^2+6y^2=33$ hence $(x,y)=(3,2)$ (for positives).

Comment: Why close this ? Aside from the fact that there are many questions of this sort.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Aside from the fact that there is no personal input whatsoever in the question, you mean? Dunno...

Comment: @6005 An even better hint would be: *use mathematics*...

Comment: See also: [Denesting
radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at
Wikipedia, [Strategies to denest nested
radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals)
(and the posts [linked
there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)),
[Denesting a square root: $\sqrt{7 +
\sqrt{14}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14)
(and the posts [linked
there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1214527)).

Comment: @Did I dont give a rats ass about personal input. I just solve math problems.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Good to know, but then why ask a reason why other users follow the rules of the site?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try to solve

$$33+12\sqrt{6} = (a+\sqrt{x})^2$$

by setting the parts without a square root equal and the parts with a square root equal.

For example, to solve:

$$\sqrt{7+4\sqrt{3}} = a+\sqrt{x}$$

Begin with

$${7+4\sqrt{3}} = (a+\sqrt{x})^2$$

$$7+4\sqrt{3} = a^2+x+2a\sqrt{x}$$

$$a^2+x=7,a\sqrt{x}=2\sqrt{3}$$

$$\vdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Not to be taken too seriously, in the sense that guessing at the values can be more fun, but here's a general formula
$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=
\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}
$$
that can be proved by squaring. Indeed, the square of the right-hand side is
$$
\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}+\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}+
2\sqrt{\frac{a^2-(a^2-b)}{4}}=a+\sqrt{b}
$$
(A different matter would be *how* to find that formula; I learned it in high school, our books had plenty of exercises where to apply it.)

In your case $a=33$ and $b=12^2\cdot 6=864$. Now
$$
a^2-b=33^2-864=1089-864=225=15^2
$$
so the formula tells us that
$$
\sqrt{33+12\sqrt{6}}=
\sqrt{\frac{33+15}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{33-15}{2}}=
\sqrt{24}+\sqrt{9}=2\sqrt{6}+3
$$

There is a companion formula:
$$
\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}=
\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mean to ask about 
$$
\sqrt{33+12\sqrt{6}}
$$
You can't tell that from the way you stated the problem.

At any rate, you expand $(a + b\sqrt{6})^2$ and get
$$
(a^2+6b^2) + 2ab\sqrt{6}
$$
And if this is going to look like $33+12\sqrt{6}$ with $a$ and $b$ integers, then $ab=6$ and there are only $4$ (or 8 including negatives) pairs to try.  You find the answer 
$3+2\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

By squaring,

$$\sqrt{33+12\sqrt6}=a+b\sqrt c\Leftarrow33+12\sqrt6=a^2+b^2c+2ab\sqrt c.$$

Then you need to solve

$$\begin{cases}a^2+b^2c=33\\ab\sqrt c=6\sqrt6.\end{cases}$$

If we assume $c=6$, we can try the factors of $6$ for $ab$:

$$1\cdot6\to1^2+6^26\ne33$$
$$2\cdot3\to2^2+3^26\ne33$$
$$3\cdot2\to3^2+2^26=33$$

and we are done.