# Proof an algebraic formula with square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, roots

If a and b are positive real numbers, then

- $\sqrt[2]{\frac{a+\sqrt[2]{a^2-b}}{2}}+\sqrt[2]{\frac{a-\sqrt[2]{a^2-b}}{2}} = \sqrt[2]{a+\sqrt[2]{b}}$

Any idea about how proof this formula is welcome.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454914/291201).

Comment: I found this: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radicale_doppio, but I'm not get it how the solution of a symmetrical equation system can be found with a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $\;u=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}\;$ and $\;v=\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}\,$. Then:

- $\require{cancel} u^2+v^2=\frac{a+\bcancel{\sqrt{a^2-b}}}{2}+\frac{a-\bcancel{\sqrt{a^2-b}}}{2}=\frac{\cancel{2}a}{\cancel{2}}=a$
- $u\,v = \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\cancel{a^2}-(\cancel{a^2}-b)}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{2}$

Therefore $\;(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv=a+\sqrt{b}\;$ which proves the posted identity.

Similarly, $\;(u-v)^2=u^2+v^2-2uv=a-\sqrt{b}\;$ which proves the related identity:

$$\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} - \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} = \sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$$