# Finding the square root of $a \pm b\sqrt c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have an exercise that says :

> Simplify $\sqrt{16+2\sqrt{55}}$.

Please, I need a vivid explanation.
Can anyone help?

Comment: here are some leads to follow https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14/1454914?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: $David Quinn$, Thanks for the link. It's really helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategies to denest  nested radicals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$16+2\sqrt{55} = 11 +5 +2\sqrt{5} \sqrt{11} = ( \sqrt{11}+ \sqrt{5})^2$$

Thus $$\sqrt{16+2\sqrt{55}}=\sqrt{11}+ \sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a^2+2ab+b^2 =(a+b)^2$. If we're lucky, we can use that. Assuming that the $2\sqrt{55}$ term corresponds in some nice way to the $2ab$ term, then most likely we have $a=\sqrt5,b=\sqrt{11}$. And, oh, look: $16=\sqrt5^2+\sqrt{11}^2$.

Comment: When I tried it, my final answer was, when a=11,b=5 and when b=11, a=5. And I'm confused which of the values of b am I expected to use. Can I use any of them?

Comment: Note that a and b are interchangeable. Whatever is a solution to a is also a solution to b. So, the solutions to a are the solutions to the problem.

Comment: @user9602923 Note that the final answer isn't to find $a$ and $b$, it is to find $16+2\sqrt{55}=(\sqrt5+\sqrt{11})^2$. If you instead find $(\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{5})^2$, that's just as valid.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks guys. Kaynex and Arthur. I'm very excited and grateful to you.